# HaProxy Configuration Error

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have 2 springboot applications running on ports 9000 and 9001. I have also run HaProxy using a docker container. My config file is as follows:

```
global

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 5000ms
    timeout server 5000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80

    acl has_web1 path_beg /web1
    acl has_web2 path_beg /web2

    use_backend web1 if has_web1 
    use_backend web2 if has_web2 

    default_backend web1

backend web1
    server web1 127.0.0.1:9000 check 

backend web2
    server web2 127.0.0.1:9001 check
```

When I try to access a url, say localhost/web1, it is giving error code 503.

Can someone tell me why is it like this?
The docker compose file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  #web1:
  #  image: dockercloud/hello-world
  #  container_name: web1
  #  ports:
  #    - "81:80"

  #web2:
  #  image: dockercloud/hello-world
  #  container_name: web2
  #  ports:
  #    - "82:80"    

  haproxy:
    build: ./haproxy
    container_name: haproxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

And the Dockerfile is:

```
FROM haproxy:1.7

COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

I am working on Windows, if that matters.

Edit: I switched to the 2.1.2 version of HaProxy and got the following warnin

```
gs:

haproxy    | [NOTICE] 020/002817 (1) : New worker #1 (6) forked
haproxy    | [WARNING] 020/002817 (6) : Server web1/web1 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
haproxy    | [ALERT] 020/002817 (6) : backend 'web1' has no server available!
haproxy    | [WARNING] 020/002818 (6) : Server web2/web2 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
haproxy    | [ALERT] 020/002818 (6) : backend 'web2' has no server available!
```

Is this because of the docker container??

Comment: are you applications running on the same docker? because you are declaring your backends as 127.0.0.1

Comment: My applications are on my local machine, they are not dockerized.

Comment: I solved the problem to some extent, but am still facing some issues. Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962271/haproxy-configuration-file-default-backend-not-running